# Validate and submit functions not calling on template.php

Tags: 7, forms, users

I have an user register form alter on my template.php and this is the code:

```
function mymodule_theme(&$existing, $type, $theme, $path){

  $hooks = array();
  $hooks['user_register_form'] = array(
    'render element'=>'form',
    'title' => 'Registro de candidatas',
    'template'    =>'templates/user-register',
  );
  return $hooks;

}

function mymodule_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  $form['mail'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title_display' => 'invisible',
    '#attributes' => array(
      'placeholder' => t('Escribe tu correo electrónico'),
      'class' => array(
        'mymodule-form-email-input'
      )
    ),
    '#required' => true
  );
  $form['pass'] = array(
    '#type' => 'password',
    '#title_display' => 'invisible',
    '#attributes' => array(
      'placeholder' => t('Escribe tu contraseña'),
      'class' => array(
        'mymodule-form-email-input'
      )
    ),
    '#required' => true
  );
  $form['captcha'] = array(
    '#type' => 'captcha',
    '#captcha_type' => 'recaptcha/reCAPTCHA',
    '#attributes' => array('class' => 'captcha')
  );
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Regístrate ahora')
  );

  $form['#validate'][] = 'mymodule_form_user_register_form_validate';
  $form['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_form_user_register_form_submit';

  return $form;

}

function mymodule_form_user_register_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {

  var_dump($form_state);

  echo 'This is my function';
  drupal_set_message(t('AN ERROR OCURED'));

  if (empty($form_state['values']['mail'])) {
    form_set_error('mail', t('Escribe un correo electrónico'));
  } else {
    if(valid_email_address($form_state['values']['mail'])) {
      form_set_error('mail', t('Email invalido')); 
    }
  }

  if (empty($form_state['values']['pass'])) {
    form_set_error('pass', t('Escribe una contraseña')); 
  }

  /*
  if (!$form_state['values']['sendgift']) {
    form_set_error(NULL, '', TRUE);
    drupal_get_messages();
  }
  */

}

function mymodule_form_user_register_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {

  echo ('This is my custom message');
  /*
  $newuser = array(
    'pass' => $form_state['values']['pass']['pass2'],
    'mail' => $form_state['values']['mail'],
    'init' => $form_state['values']['mail'],
    'status' => 1,
  );         
  $user = user_save('', $newuser);
  $user->password = $pass; // Add plain text password into user account to generate mail tokens.
  _user_mail_notify('register_no_approval_required', $user);

  drupal_set_message('Tu registro ha sido procesado, ahora ve a tu email y activalo!');
  */

}
```

And I have the callbacks `mymodule_form_user_register_form_validate` and `mymodule_form_user_register_form_submit` inside `mymodule_form_user_register_form_alter` but these functions aren't called when I submit the form. Something wrong here? Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73196/discussion-on-question-by-josotoru-validate-and-submit-functions-not-calling-on).

Answer (score 0):

The hook [*hook_form_FORM_ID_alter*](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7.x) does not return a variable. The *$form* variable is passed by reference so it can be modified inside the alter hook.

Remove the **return $form;** line from your **mymodule_form_user_register_form_alter** function.

Make sure you clear your cache after code changes to any of those functions.